# Jquery filter select options by attribute option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select boxes.

1st is maincategory

2nd is subcategory

The maincategories and subcategories options are given a data-key.

```
<option data-key="0">First</option>
<option data-key="1">Second</option>
```

etc..

Now I want to filter the second subcat select box on the data-key when the user changes the main category.

When ever the user changes the maincategory I get the data-key by :

```
var key = $('.maincat').find('option:selected').attr("data-key");
```

Afther this I want to filter the .subcat select box to only display data with data-key = key.

Any ideas on that ?

Comment: and not because you filter by the value?

Comment: I dont know how to filter the second select box options on the data-key attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide or show the options in `.subcat` depending on whether their `data-key` matches `key`.

```
$(".subcat option").each(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).data("key") == key);
});
```

Comment: Thanks going to try it right now.. Googled a lot, this is nice approach I believe..

Comment: Whats the difference between : .data("key") which you use and .attr("data-key"); I noticed the difference when reading your code.